# How can I display info from sharedPreferences after the activity or app gets closed?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have put some information that I want to be displayed even after my app or activity gets closed. I have a function display and if I call it in `onCreate()` or `onStart()` my app crashes.

```
public void display()  {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MedInfo", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        mText1.setText(sharedPref.getString("mText1", ""));
    }
```

Here's how the data gets saved

```
    public void savemMed1() {

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MedInfo", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("mText1", addMed.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

[image: This is the part written with red from the Logcat:]

This is the line that does not fit in the picture:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{corina_holom.com.medplannerapp/corina_holom.com.medplannerapp.Reminder}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

This is my first time programming in java and android studio and I'm having trouble finding tutorials that help. I'm not sure how I should change this or if I should use **onStart()**

This is the Code from the activity in which I want the info displayed:

```
public class Reminder extends AppCompatActivity {

public TextView mText1, mText2, mText3;
private EditText addMed;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder);
    defineButtons();

}

public void defineButtons() {
    findViewById(R.id.mB1).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
    findViewById(R.id.mB2).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
    //findViewById(R.id.mB3).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);

}

private View.OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.mB1:
                addMed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addMed);
                mText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mText1);
                mText1.setText(addMed.getText());
                savemMed1();

                break;
            case R.id.mB2:
                addMed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addMed);
                mText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mText2);
                mText2.setText(addMed.getText());
                break;
        }
    }
};

public void savemMed1() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MedInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("mText1", addMed.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Comment: First try to find the problem that is causing the crash.

Comment: It does not have any errors. The app starts running on my phone but when I click on the button that opens the activity in which I want the info to be displayed it crashes. This happens only when display() is called in onCreate() or onStart().

Comment: I think you mean that there are no errors during build/compile time, but If the app crashes it means that there are errors during runtime. Once the app crashes you can see the error log in the Logcat section which you can find at the bottom of Android Studio. Over there choose Error filter and you will see the error log, the section that you are interested in will probably have lines in blue which direct to the part of your code that are causing a crash

Comment: Is what's in the picture enough?

Comment: mText1 = findViewById(R.id.textview);

Comment: Isn't the id supposed to be the one from the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that by the time you use `setText` your textview is not initialised. Make sure you do `findViewById` before you do `setText`. The best way is to do it first thing in `onCreate`. And of course make sure that the id is the same as in the layout.

Comment: I added the entire code. I thought it initialises the textview before setText

Comment: @CorinaHolom Do not do `findViewById` in onClickListener do it in onCreate, initialise all your views in `onCreate` directly like this `mText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mText1)`

Comment: @CorinaHolom Glad it helped :) Just for the future, only do `findViewById` once and first thing. So for example, in `onCreate` you do `mTextView1 = findViewById(R.id.mText1)`, and after that use `mTextView1` to set the `onClickListener` like this `mTextView1 = setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);`.